# Can i use GMGridview edit and sort mode enabled at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using GMGridview in a iOS app and i want to enable delete mode and sort mode at the same time(Long press). Right now it can only be delete or sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible by subclassing `GMGridview`.

Check out [this](http://roshankularathna.blogspot.com/2013/03/gmgridview-long-press-delete-and-moving.html) link.

Comment: Even if the link provides the necessary information, it is recommended to include the gist of it here as well in case the link gets outdated. Also a better link description would be good!